# Use gapi.client javascript to execute my custom Google API

Tags: google-api-js-client

I have a service that is successfully deployed to Google Endpoints and it is accessible through browser.

Now I am trying to load Google API javascript client library to call my services using javascript.

As far as I know, I should do this

```
gapi.client.load([MY_APP_NAME], 'v1', function() {
   var request = gapi.client.[API_NAME].[SERVICE_NAME].[METHOD]();
   request.execute(function(jsonResp, rawResp) {...});
   );
```

But I always get an exception at run time complaining about **gapi.client.[MY_API_NAME]** is undefined. I do the same thing with any Google API (such as Plus) and it works fine. For example, If I load 'plus' API, I will have access to gapi.client.plus... and I can call methods.

Am I missing something? All samples and documents are about Google Service APIs and I could not find a sample for custom APIs (the one that developers write).

I even tried gapi.client.request with different paths (absolute path and relative path) but I get 404 - Not Found error in "status".

```
var request = gapi.client.request({'path':
'https://[APP_NAME].appspot.com/_ah/api/[SERVICE_NAME]/v1/[METHOD]'
, 'method': 'GET'});
request.execute(function(jsonResp, rawResp) {...});


var request = gapi.client.request({
'path':'/[SERVICE_NAME]/v1/[METHOD]',
'method': 'GET'});
request.execute(function(jsonResp, rawResp) {...});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was a missing parameter in calling gapi.client.load().

I looked at the definition of gapi.client.load at this link https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientload

```
gapi.client.load(name, version, callback)
```

which then later I found out is not totally correct and an optional parameter is missing (**app_api_root_url**).

```
gapi.client.load(name, version, callback, app_api_root_url)
```

If the app_api_root_url is missing, the client is loaded for Google Service APIs only (app_api_root_url such as https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api)

You can find more details on how to use gapi.client.load() properly at this link https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js

As you can see in the following piece of code, I didn't have **ROOT** parameter when I was calling **gapi.client.load** and that is why Google by default was looking at its own service API and obviously could not find my APIs.

```
   var ROOT = 'https://your_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/api';

   gapi.client.load('your_api_name', 'v1', function() {

      var request = gapi.client.your_api_name.your_method_name();
      request.execute(function(jsonResp, rawResp) {
                        //do the rest of what you need to do
                      });

   }, ROOT);
```

NOTE: **your_app_id** is used in ROOT parameter only to load the client script. After loading is done, **you will have an object that is named after your API** and not your app. That object is like your Java (service) class and you can use to invoke methods directly.